# Find files with comments with Google Drive API v3

Tags: google-drive-api

Is it possible to find files with a `q` arg in the `service.files().list()` method, so that only files with comments are retrieved?

If not, then is there a `field` to mark such files that have comments?

I have looked at [Query reference](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/query-ref) to no avail.

Comment: Depending on what you want to achieve you have different options. Are you trying to detect new comments? Making a report? Detected files that need attention? More information about the end goal would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

With `q` one could only query `replies` (as this is a property of `File` and therefore can be queried for). So you'd have to `list` all the `files` and then `list` the associated comments. When there's more than `0` comments, just push that `fileId` into an array; maybe also the number (length) of comments.

At first [this one](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list):

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files
```

And then [this one](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/comments/list):

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{fileId}/comments
```

Comment: Currently I am listing all the files and for each file, retrieving the comment. But that is taking a long time, I have hundreds of files. Also, the `replies` are only about reply to the comment, right? I do not have any reply to the comments. Just the comment itself.

Comment: Well, performance was not the question... you still could setup a notification, when a comment is added and then track these in a separate database, which would speed up things a lot. I can only confirm that the API offers no other way that I'd be aware of.